# How to read a struct from a JS ArrayBuffer efficiently (browser)?

Tags: javascript, performance, struct, arraybuffer

Let's say I have a struct of the form

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t intensity;
  uint16_t ring;
  float32_t x;
  float32_t y;
  float32_t z;
} Point;
```

(18 bytes total) and I have a huge array of several tens of thousands of these 18-byte structs in an ArrayBuffer.

How do I iterate through them efficiently without calling a "new DataView()" constructor irritatively in a loop?

This is in the browser, not NodeJS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to create a new `DataView` each time you read a value. Create it just once and use `offset` to read data at the specific location:

```
let dv = new DataView(buffer);
let offset = 0;

while (offset < buffer.byteLength) {
    intensity = dv.getUint32(offset);  offset += 32;
    ring = dv.getUint16(offset);       offset += 16;
    // etc
}
```

}